# How to create multiple files out of one file, then name each file based on a string inside the file?

Tags: bash

I am trying to split a file based on the word "resource" and name the file, from the example below, the file would be named granola.tf and the last one would be named airnow.tf:

```
resource "github_repository" "Granola" {
  name        = "Granola"
  private     = false
  description = "Something"
  has_wiki    = "false"
  has_downloads = "true"
  has_issues  = "false"
  archived    = "false"
}

...

resource "github_repository" "airnow" {
  name        = "airnow"
  private     = false
  description = "Something"
  has_wiki    = "true"
  has_downloads = "true"
  has_issues  = "true"
  archived    = "false"
}
```

I have been trying to use the csplit command and think I need to do something with this, but have no idea how to name the files differently, I know I should be able to do it using the prefix argument but am unable to figure it out This is what I have tried below:

```
for i in $numberofresourceblocks; do
    csplit --prefix=PREFIX --elide-empty-files repositories.tf 
    /resource/ {1}
done
```

I expect to get a given number of files (how many resource blocks there are) with different names based on the naming convention above. Any idea on how to achieve this? Also, not all the resource blocks will be the same amount of lines.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
csplit --elide-empty-files repositories.tf '/resource/' '{*}'
for file in xx*
do
    new=$(awk '{gsub("\"","",$3); print $3; exit}' "$file")
    mv "$file" "$new.tf"
done
```

Explanation:

- Split the file according to the pattern, using the pattern repeatedly (`{*}`)
- For each resulting file, get the third field on the first line and remove the quotes
- Rename the file

This should be run in the directory containing `repositories.tf` and the resulting files will be output in that same directory.

This assumes that none of the resulting names will collide (i.e. there aren't two Granolas) and that none will collide with "repositories.tf".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and you want to split the contents of your file into the separate files `Granola` and `airnow`, then there is no reason to use `csplit`. You can do everything you want with GNU `awk` using simple *redirection*. For example, given your input file (called `file`)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat file
resource "github_repository" "Granola" {
  name        = "Granola"
  private     = false
  description = "Something"
  has_wiki    = "false"
  has_downloads = "true"
  has_issues  = "false"
  archived    = "false"
}


resource "github_repository" "airnow" {
  name        = "airnow"
  private     = false
  description = "Something"
  has_wiki    = "true"
  has_downloads = "true"
  has_issues  = "true"
  archived    = "false"
}
```

A single call to `awk` that check if the line begins with `resource` and stores the line while isolating the output filename from `$3` using `substr` and `length`, then checks if the first field is `name` and redirects the saved line and the current line to the filename, and finally redirects the remaining lines with `length` greater than zero to the output filename is all you need, e.g.

**Example Use**

```
$ awk '
    /^resource/ { line=$0; fname=substr($3, 2, length ($3)-2); next }
    $1 == "name" { print line > fname; print $0 > fname; next}
    length($0) > 0 {print $0 > fname}
' file
```

**Resulting Output Files**

Running the above on your input `file` would result in the file being separated into the two separate files `Granola`:

```
$ cat Granola
resource "github_repository" "Granola" {
  name        = "Granola"
  private     = false
  description = "Something"
  has_wiki    = "false"
  has_downloads = "true"
  has_issues  = "false"
  archived    = "false"
}
```

and the `airnow` file:

```
$ cat airnow
resource "github_repository" "airnow" {
  name        = "airnow"
  private     = false
  description = "Something"
  has_wiki    = "true"
  has_downloads = "true"
  has_issues  = "true"
  archived    = "false"
}
```